# how to stop image from caching in php

Tags: php, html, image

I am having this problem of image i.e image is not reloading on page refresh as it is an .gif image and i have to show the transition on each page refresh.

```
<?php if ($page == "index") { ?>
        <img src="images/Karpel_logo.gif" alt="" />
        <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="http://www.karpellaw.com/test"><img id="graph" src="images/Karpel_logo.gif?dummy=371662" alt="" /></a>
        <?php } ?>

 live link :    www.karpellaw.com/test
```

Comment: I have tried adding a dummy field along with the image , used an javascript for the image to load on the basis of time and date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use random integer for every page refresh. It will forcefully load new image rather then cached image.

```
<img src="images/Karpel_logo.gif?<?php echo rand(); ?>" alt="" />
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="http://www.karpellaw.com/test"><img id="graph" src="images/Karpel_logo.gif?dummy=<?php echo rand(); ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a ?a=time()

```
<?php if ($page == "index") { 
          echo '<img src="images/Karpel_logo.gif?a='.time().'" alt="" />';
         } else {
        echo '<a href="http://www.karpellaw.com/test"><img id="graph" src="images/Karpel_logo.gif?dummy=371662&a='.time().'" alt="" /></a>'
     } 
?>
```

Comment: must be `.gif?a='. time() .'" alt=""`

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you refresh the page, change the src of the image tag :

```
<img src="images/Karpel_logo.gif?<?php echo time();?>" alt="" />
```

OR you can append any random number and the end of the image src.